# Print Select Option Using Ajax, Jquery and a PHP Echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked throughout Stackoverflow and seen numerous examples of this but none give the answer how to echo. I am have a select dropdown that is on a page called testing.php:

```
<form id="projects" action="project-add.php" method="POST">
<select name="territory" id="territory">
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
</select>

// A fair few more form fields here

<input type="submit" value="Submit Project">
</form>
```

I now need whatever is selected here to be available to echo as a php variable later down the form without the need to press a button.

I have the following script in the :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#territory').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#territory option').removeAttr('selected');
    $(selectedOption).attr('selected','selected');
    var selectedOptionValue = $(selectedOption).val();
    var selectedOptionText = $(selectedOption).text();


    $.ajax({
    url: 'testing.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {data : selectedOptionText},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){ }
 });
 });//]]>


 });

</script>
```

I would then like to print:

```
<? echo $_POST['data']; ?>
```

But this isn't working.  Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't access a `$_POST` variable without actually posting, you can use your `ajax success callback` if you want to use the variable for displaying it. Can you please explain what's your main objective?

Comment: I need to use the variable that is outputted in an SQL query later on down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/getcountry.html)

**1.** You need to be able to trigger the change

```
<select name="territory" id="territory">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
</select>
```

**2.** then call the php with the selected option

```
$(function() { // on page load
  $('#territory').on("change",function(e) {
    $("#someOutputContainerID").empty(); // clear the container
    var selectedOptionValue = $(this).val();
    if (selectedOptionValue) { // in case they select "Please select"
      $.ajax({
        url: 'testing.php', 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: {data : selectedOptionValue },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data){
          $("#someOutputContainerID").html(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The selected value is now available in the testing.php as `$_POST["data"]` and anything echoed in testing.php will show in the container

Comment: I basically need to write an SQL query with that variable in it.  So WHERE COUNTRY = '$outputVariable'

Comment: I can't seem to get it to print this out.  I understand the workings.  Anyway you could demo it?

Comment: When you say "print" do you mean "display" or "print on printer"? and what problem do you have? Any console errors? PHP errors?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to use that variable in the page itself and not in `testing.php`.

Comment: @OfirBaruch OP just said he wants to do an sql query

Comment: I mean post it on the page so I could use: $variable = $_POST['data']; then use $variable in the SQL query on testing.php

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have an element in which you want to display it. In my example I call it `#element`.

Use the `selectedOptionValue` in your JS script to display the value inside `#element` by adding this line `$('#element').text( selectedOptionValue );`

Complete function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#territory').change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $('#territory option').removeAttr('selected');
    $(selectedOption).attr('selected','selected');
    var selectedOptionValue = $(selectedOption).val();

    /* Added this rule */
    $('#element').text( selectedOptionValue );

    var selectedOptionText = $(selectedOption).text();


    $.ajax({
    url: 'testing.php', 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: {data : selectedOptionText},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){ }
 });
 });//]]>


 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you post won't be available in php's `$_POST` superglobal; you need to catch it in the response from ajax. This does rely on 'testing.php' echoing out the appropriate response (maybe using `json_encode`) to make sure. You can experiment with your reponse using `console.log(response)` before you start putting it into the DOM too.

The answer from LinkinTED also works beautifully, although arguably using ajax is more appropriate - inasmuch as it will only display if the ajax response comes back properly.

It does depend what `testing.php` does though; if the ajax function writes to a database, then definitely better to use ajax - if you literally just want to generate text down the page however, better to stick to javascript and rely on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code, tested and works 100%

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#territory').on('change', function() {
                var selectedOptionText = $("#territory option:selected").text();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'testing.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {data: selectedOptionText},
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (data) {
                         alert("success"+data);
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. testing.php echos the posted value. Since you are accessing it through an ajax call, response itself is getting to the ajax success function. If you want to use the data coming from your testing.php modify your success function accordingly.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'testing.php', 
type: 'POST', 
data: {data : selectedOptionText},
dataType: 'text',
success: function(data)
{
    $("body").append(data);
}
```

If you want to use the posted value out side the scope of this page and testing.php page, you need to save it some where (in a session, database, etc.).